# how to remove item from 2nd spinner that are used in 1st spinner android kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-spinner

I have created two spinners.I want to remove the items in second list that are shown in 1st list of spinners.
I need all this code in kotlin.Please explain and give sample code in kotlin.
I have to load all data in both spinner from string.xml file.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.graphics.Insets.add
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val spinner1: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1)
        val spinner2: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2)

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.planets_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner1.adapter = adapter
        }
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.planets_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner2.adapter = adapter
        }
        class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {
               
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // Another interface callback
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

Please help how can i remove the item that shown in 1st spinner.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Yes i can.I am updating it

Comment: Try this, in onItemSelected use "pos" to remove an item from adapter2 from that position and use notifyOnDataChanged or whatever you have.

Comment: can you give me sample code, Please.Thanks

Comment: Please help me.show me sample code.

Comment: Do you know how to code in Java?

Comment: i know little.I am a beginner,

Comment: Please help me if i can do it in kotlin.